# NO PUEDO SUBIR EL TOKEN PARA RESOLVER RECAPTCHA CON LA API 2CAPTHCA, PYTHON, SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

Estoy utilizando la API 2Captcha para obtener el token que resuelve el reCaptcha de una web que valida los antecedentes penales de una persona, insertando el DNI y el código de verificación. El caso es que mi código funciona en la [demo de reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) pero no en la página que quiero https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/verificaCSV. Al hacer click en el botón Consutlar después de inyectar el token en el área de texto debería funcionar, pero no funciona (la página se vuelve a cargar y el reCaptha no se resuelve), no sé qué paso me estoy saltando. Agradecería si hay alguien que pueda identificar que parte de la pagina web envía el token para solucionar el reCaptcha, tengo la entrega del trabajo este domingo y ningún foro ni video soluciona mi problema. ¡Gracias!. El código:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

#Death By Captcha
import requests, time

page_url = 'https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/verificaCSV'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(page_url)

def solve():
    result = None
    sitekey = '6Lf28LAUAAAAACso2fkzeLfJLKN1DBHUrVNpIN1b'
    api_key = 'MY_API_KEY'
    solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
    try:
        result = solver.recaptcha(
            sitekey=sitekey,
            url='https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/verificaCSV'
        )

    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(e)

    return result

numero_dni = 'ID'
codigo_verificacion = 'VERIFICATION_CODE'

insertarDNI = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
                .until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#documento.inputMediano")))\
                .send_keys(str(numero_dni))

insertarCodigo_Verificacion = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
                .until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#idSolicitud.inputMediano")))\
                .send_keys(str(codigo_verificacion))

textarea = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'g-recaptcha-response')
solution = solve()
code = solution['code']
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('g-recaptcha-response')[0].style.display = '';")
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'g-recaptcha-response').send_keys(code)
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitConsulta").click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)

Comment: 2captcha te da un límite, pasado el límite debes pagar.

Comment: Cómo que un límite? Por eso no llega a verificarse el reCaptcha?